# Accurev change name of a workspace

Tags: accurev

I need to rename a workspace created in accurev.

How can it be made with accurev GUI or CLI?

In the case of regular stream it is possible with a "change stream" option, but fro workspace this option is not active.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GUI:  View -> Workspaces -> Select Workspace -> Right Click -> Edit -> Change name

CLI: accurev chws -w oldname newname

Comment: Thanks! Sometimes GUI is not as intuitive as it should.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to rename the Stream.

GUI -> Right Click on Stream -> Change Stream -> In name give the new name